# Using Breeze with RequireJS, Angular is loaded

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, typescript, breeze, amd

Using TypeScript, AMD, "requirejs", "breeze" but not "angular", I just upgraded from Breeze 1.4.0 to 1.4.6. Now, when "breeze" is loaded, it also tries to load "angular" which fails with...

```
Module name "angular" has not been loaded yet for context: _. 
Use require([]) http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
```

The problem seems to result from Breeze executing the following line.

```
var ng = core.requireLib("angular");
```

What have I done wrong so this code is executed anyway? Why does Breeze think that Angular has to be loaded?

When replacing the above line with the following, anything works fine.

```
var ng = undefined;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having trouble reproducing this.

True, due to a peculiarity in the Breeze code, Breeze will execute the following line even when angular is not present

```
var ng = core.requireLib("angular");
```

... and that will fail with

```
Module name "angular" has not been loaded yet for context
```

because it can't find a library called angular.js (I assume you don't have it)

But that failure occurs inside another function (`__requireLibCore`) within a `try/catch`

```
function __requireLibCore(libName) {
    var lib;
    try {
        if (this.window) {
            ...
            if (window.require) {
                lib = window.require(libName);
            }
            if (lib) return lib;
        }
    } catch(e) {

}
return lib;
```

Are you seeing some other code path in which this error is thrown?

### UPDATE 11 December 2013

Thanks, @mgs, for your email explaining how you saw the exception. I summarize for those who read this later.

Breeze started looking for AngularJS in v.1.4.6. To be perfectly clear, Breeze **does not need angular**; it just wants to know if angular is available. Breeze doesn’t need knockout, jQuery or Q either. But under varying circumstances it may look for these libraries and use them if it finds them.

AFAIK there is no other way in requireJS to detect if a module has been loaded then to call `require("angular")`. Unfortunately, `require("angular")` throws an exception when it can't find that module.

Breeze itself does not fail because that call is caught in a try/catch. Many (most?) devs will never see this exception.

But @mgs has **attached a `requirejs.onError` event handler** ... which I hasten to add **is a good practice**. Of course his handler will see the "angular not found" exception even though Breeze caught it and moved on. He writes:

> That “requirejs.onError” function is called, when Breeze tries to load Angular. In the real program this causes an entry into the log, and alarm bells are ringing. It was this entry that made me ask the question on StackOverflow.

What  to do? I don't think Breeze can do anything unless someone knows a way to detect a loaded module without triggering the `requirejs.onError` event. I think it is up to the developer to compensate.

I recommend teaching your handler to ignore Breeze's attempt to find angular. Don't sound the "alarm bell" for this particular failure.

Alternatively, you could define a dummy module, as @mgs, did so that require finds an "angular" module. I'm not fond of this approach because it fools Breeze into believing that Angular is available and Breeze might act on that misunderstanding in the future. It's harmless today but who knows about tomorrow.

In any event, the mystery has been explained and suitable workarounds are now known. Thanks, @mgs, for the opportunity to explore this subject.

### UPDATE 12 December 2013

We just released Breeze v.1.4.7 which includes the change you recommended ... using `require.defined` to check first if a module is loaded. Works like a charm.

I took the occasion to re-write the [Todo-Require sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/todo-require) such that everything is loaded in a single require script line:

```
<!-- Require + main. All scripts retrieved async by requireJS -->
<script data-main="Scripts/app/main" src="Scripts/require.js"></script>
```

The documentation explains how it all works.

Thanks for your question and feedback.

Comment: I did some more debugging. You are right. The error is thrown in the above function. However, with the base libraries that are in use here, there is an active `requirejs.onError` function. It is the one that reports the error and that made me ask this question. Maybe it would be better, if Breeze only required Angular if it was told to do so. However, I have a workaround by defining a dummy module `angular`, which simply returns `undefined`.

Comment: I tried that. But it didn't seem necessary. **My question for you ... how did you see this exception?**  I can't get it because Breeze wraps the exception in a try/catch. How did you see it?

Comment: P.s.: I have a request in to delay looking for angular until necessary. But I still want to know how you got this error because the hunt for angular, while wasteful, should be harmless.

Comment: I do not yet know, why my case is so special. But I will prepare some information on the scenario. If necessary, I will send a demo project.

Comment: Maybe you can use require.defined and require.specified for finding out about whether a certain module is loaded or known.

Comment: How about that ... an undocumented feature. Neither `defined` nor `specified` are in the standard but requirejs does implement `defined`. I'll see if I can have Breeze make use of that in the next release. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

you can force angularjs to be loaded by adding the following typescript line:

`/// <amd-dependency path="angular"/>`

alternatively you can make `breeze` depend on `angular` in your requirejs config.

**Update** In case you are *not using angularjs* you can safely exclude this file from your project : https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Breeze.Client/Scripts/IBlade/b00_breeze.ajax.angular.js

Comment: Currently, I do not use angular. Nor do I want to use angular in the future. The problem is that Breeze executes the above `core.requireLib("angular")`, although I have done nothing that has anything to do with Angular. So the question is: what might make Breeze think that Angular has to be loaded?

Comment: There is no such file. Breeze Javascript was added to the project via Nuget `Breeze.Client`. Now there are `breeze.debug.js` and `breeze.min.js`.

Comment: You can safely delete the whole portion from `breeze.debug.js` that represents that file and then minify it yourself

Comment: As I told, coding `var ng = undefined;` makes it work. Also defining `"angular"` to be a function returning `undefined` makes it work. But this can't be the final solution to the problem. Shouldn't Breeze work right out of the box without any tricks?